# Unique maximal ideal containing $(X,Y^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to show that there is a unique maximal ideal in $K[X,Y]$ which contains the ideal $(X,Y^3)$, namely $(X,Y)$.
Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that $K$ is a field in your question.

The ideals of $K[X,Y]$ containing $(X,Y^3)$ are in bijection with the ideals of $K[X,Y]/(X,Y^3)$, and this bijection preserves inclusions.  In view of this, what you want to show is that the ring $K[X,Y]/(X,Y^3)$ contains a unique maximal ideal (such rings are called local rings).

To do this, one could first show that $K[X,Y]/(X,Y^3)$ is isomorphic to $K[Y]/(Y^3)$, and then prove that this last ring is local (its only maximal ideal is generated by $Y$).

Comment: And how do I prove that $K[Y]/ (Y^3)$ is local?

Comment: @J.Karen  As a hint, I would say: characterize the invertible elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

A maximal ideal is prime.
On the other hand $K[X,Y]/(X,Y)\simeq K$.

Comment: And since $K$ is a field, it has a unique maximal ideal. However, I don't know how to use that in order to prove that it is the unique maximal ideal...

Comment: It is the only maximal ideal *which contains* $X, Y^3)$ since any maximal ideal containing $X$ and $Y^3$ has to contain it, and it *is* maximal. A maximal ideal can't be contained  in another maximal ideal.

Comment: But why any maximal ideal containing $X$ and $Y^3$ has to contain $Y$?

Comment: A maximal ideal is prime.